# AWS Glue Crawler - Timestamp field created as string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a data file with a field called `extraction_time` that has fields like below.

`..,"extraction_time":"2022-03-15T02:33:39",..`

On my crawler I have a Classifier that looks like so:
[image: Crawler Classifier Image]

However, when I look at the table that is created, `extraction_time` is always of the string type.

[image: Extraction Field Type in Table]

How do I ensure that when my crawler creates the table, it identifies the `extraction_time` field as a timestamp and not a string?

Any help is greatly appreciated